# How best to query a 1:many:many relationship efficiently using the SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Here's the code

```py
    with Role.get_session() as session:
        query = session.query(User, UserGroup, UserToUserGroup, UserGroupToRole, Role)\
            .filter(User.user_id == UserToUserGroup.columns.user_id)\
            .filter(UserToUserGroup.columns.user_group_id == UserGroup.user_group_id)\
            .filter(UserToUserGroup.columns.user_group_id == UserGroupToRole.columns.user_group_id)\
            .filter(UserGroupToRole.columns.role_id == Role.role_id)\
            .filter(User.user_id == user_id)

        current_app.logger.error(str(query))
        res = query.all()
```

In short, this query is super .. bad, in all senses as far as I can tell. `UserToUserGroup` and `UserGroupToRole` are pivot tables, and are defined as

```py
UserGroupToRole = Table("UserGroupsToRoles", base.metadata,
                        Column("user_group_id", INTEGER(unsigned=True), ForeignKey("UserGroups.user_group_id")),
                        Column("role_id", INTEGER(unsigned=True), ForeignKey("Roles.role_id")))


UserToUserGroup = Table("UsersToUserGroups", base.metadata,
                        Column("user_id", INTEGER(unsigned=True), ForeignKey("Users.user_id")),
                        Column("user_group_id", INTEGER(unsigned=True), ForeignKey("UserGroups.user_group_id")))
```

The other three models are pretty standard. `User` has a `1:many` relationship to `UserGroup` via the pivot table `UserToUserGroup`. `UserGroup` has a `1:many` relationship to `Role` via `UserGroupToRole` pivot table.

All relationships defined on these models are `lazy="joined"`

**Question:** How do I map a user (by supplied user id) to all associated `Roles`, efficiently? All I want to return are `Role` instances, for a given `user_id`

I recognize that this will return all data between `User` and `Role` instances (including other relationships not specified by the query, since even those are lazy=joined), which isn't desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using joins should simplify the query, it might also be more efficient but I cannot prove that assertion:

```
with Role.get_session() as session:
    roles = session.query(Role)\
        .join(UserGroupToRole)\
        .join(UserGroup)\
        .join(UserToUserGroup)\
        .join(User)\
        .filter(User.user_id == user_id)\
        .all()
```

Comment: Yeah, I should have noticed that. That definitely helps dramatically, and actually returns instead of hanging and being killed. This is what I get for working past when my brain gave out!